# Why the MouseLeave event is not triggered when folderbrowserdialog was open and selected a directory?

Tags: c#, winforms, mouseevent, custom-controls

I have a custom button that has different colors when `MouseEnter`, `MouseLeave`, `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`. But when a `FolderBrowserDialog` was open after `MouseClick` and selected a directory from it, the color stays still on the `MouseEnter` color despite of mouse is out of the button. I can't figure out why this happens. I have tried to solve the issue using `Capture`, but it didn't work for me. Maybe I used it wrongly.

My code's events part in `MyButton` class:

```
//.....

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //.....
        #region Drawing
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        roundedRect = new RoundedRectangle(Width, Height, radius);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Transparent, this.ClientRectangle);

        int R1 = (active1.R + inactive1.R) / 2;
        int G1 = (active1.G + inactive1.G) / 2;
        int B1 = (active1.B + inactive1.B) / 2;

        int R2 = (active2.R + inactive2.R) / 2;
        int G2 = (active2.G + inactive2.G) / 2;
        int B2 = (active2.B + inactive2.B) / 2;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height);

        if (this.Enabled)
        {
            if (state == MouseState.Leave)
                using (LinearGradientBrush inactiveGB = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, inactive1, inactive2, 90f))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(inactiveGB, roundedRect.Path);
            else if (state == MouseState.Over)
                using (LinearGradientBrush activeGB = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, active1, active2, 90f))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(activeGB, roundedRect.Path);
            else if (state == MouseState.Down)
                using (LinearGradientBrush downGB = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.FromArgb(R1, G1, B1), Color.FromArgb(R2, G2, B2), 90f))
                    e.Graphics.FillPath(downGB, roundedRect.Path);
            using (LinearGradientBrush BorderGB = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, inactive1, inactive2, 90f))
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(BorderGB), roundedRect.Path);
        }
        else
        {
            Color linear1 = Color.FromArgb(190, 190, 190);
            Color linear2 = Color.FromArgb(210, 210, 210);
            using (LinearGradientBrush inactiveGB = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, linear1, linear2, 90f))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillPath(inactiveGB, roundedRect.Path);
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(inactiveGB), roundedRect.Path);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    //.....
    }
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClick(e);
    }
    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        state = MouseState.Over;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        state = MouseState.Leave;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        state = MouseState.Down;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        state = MouseState.Up;
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
    #endregion
    //.....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue changing the `MouseUp` event code. There is no need `MouseState.Up` in this.

```
//code
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(state != MouseState.Leave)
           state = MouseState.Over
        Invalidate();
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }
//code
```